# Does a web file exist - using same function to get the Content Type

Tags: c#, function, asp.net-mvc-5, content-type, file-exists

I have a function that is coded to get the `Content-Type` of a web file.

Here is the function:

```
public string GetContentTypeOfUri(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
            return (contentType);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Rather than writing a whole different function to detect if a web file exists, how can I calculate if a file exists from the same code as used to get the `Content-Type`?

If I use a uri of a file that does not exist, an exception occurs. The ex.HResult equals -2146233079 when this exception occurs, with a message = "The remote name could not be resolved: '[address name]'".

Is it safe to say that when an exception occurs, and the ex.HResult equals -2146233079, the file does not exist?

Is there an easier/better way to work this out?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the `HttpClient` code that I have:

```
public async Task<string> GetContentTypeAsync(string uri)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        request.Method = new HttpMethod("HEAD");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        string contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
        return contentType;
    }
}
```

Your example web address does inform me that the address does not exist, however, if I have a web address that does not exist such as http://www.usa.canon.com/app/html/HDV/HG10/images/hg10_sample_image_03.jpg5, I am getting a StatusCode of OK, as a Text content type is returned as a custom error page.

Comment: Sounds fair - if you can't get it then it does not exist. If you have better/other definition of "exists" then just write code that matches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible "not exists" scenarios. It sounds like you've identified one of them - when the server name in the URL is incorrect and so the request cannot even be sent.

But you're not accounting for the other error - that you *can* reach a remote server but it denies all knowledge of a specific file. For that scenario, you ought to be checking for status [`404`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) on the `response`.

For cleaner handling of your current scenario (server doesn't exist) you could use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class to extract the `Host` name from the `uri` string and perform a manual [DNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns(v=vs.110).aspx) lookup - which would allow you to code for this likely scenario without having to catch exceptions - which is generally frowned upon when its an expected scenario.

Comment: Do you have an example uri that I can use to test the status result? Whenever I choose a uri that does not exist, the code jumps straight to the exception, and I cannot check the 404 status.

Comment: [http://www.google.com/SomeFileThatDoesntExist](http://www.google.com/SomeFileThatDoesntExist)?

Comment: The code jumps to the exception, and there is no code to work out the status.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd misremembered how [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) works - when it receives an error, you do get a `WebException` which, itself, contains the response object that you should examine. You might also want to consider switching to `HttpClient` which is the newer http class which (more properly, in my opinion) treats receiving non-200 status codes as part of the normal use of http rather than throwing an exception.